Using AROC to determine the explicit formula of a sequence - why does this work?
Take, for example, the sequence (for $n\ge0$):$$\begin{array}{c|c}n&x_n\\\hline0&5\\\hline1&6\\\hline2&9\\\hline3&14\\\hline4&21\\\hline\vdots&\vdots\end{array}$$Now, one way one could determine an explicit formula is by taking the average rate of change of the sequence, like so for this example, where taking the AROC (taken from $n$ to $n+1$) the first time gives us$$\begin{array}{c|c}n&x_{n+1}-x_n\\\hline0&1\\\hline1&3\\\hline2&5\\\hline3&7\\\hline4&9\\\hline\vdots&\vdots\end{array}$$And here, it is probably possible to tell that the explicit formula for $x_n$ is quadratic in nature, either by

Noticing that the explicit formula of $x_{n+1}-x_n$ is $2x+1$ (with leading term 2), and then letting$$x_n:=n^2+c\implies x_0=5=0^2+c\\\implies c=5\implies x_n:=n^2+5$$
Or by calculating the AROC a second time (which is basically equivalent to computing $x_{n+2}-2x_{n+1}+x_n$, which I'll now define as $a_n$), which gives us the table$$\begin{array}{c|c}n&a_n\\\hline0&2\\\hline1&2\\\hline2&2\\\hline3&2\\\hline4&2\\\hline\vdots&\vdots\end{array}$$and then note that the sequence is quadratic in nature and follow the steps in the first bullet point to find the explicit formula.


My question is: What's the intuition behind this working? I understand that it does work, but what I've never really understood is why.

To be clear, it only works when it is assumed that the sequence must be polynomial.  It only works when it is assumed that the explicit formula of $x_{n+1}-x_n$ truly continued as it appeared to do as being $2x+1$ and that it didn't suddenly stop following that pattern just after where what information was given to us had ended.

The situations is similar to differentiation. When you differentiate a polynomial you reduced the highest power by 1:
$$ \frac{d}{d\, x} x^p  = p \cdot x^{p-1} $$
The situation is similar with finite differences:
When you build differences of
$$ (n+1)^p - n^p = p \cdot n^{p-1} + \ldots + 1 $$
so each time you do the finite differences you get a sequence of values from a polynomial of degree one less then before.
